# How to run a specific set of java code at a particular date and time requested by user

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I want my java program to be run at a specific date and time requested by the user which will be in the form of `Timestamp` the requested timestamp will be stored in the database and the code should start running at that point of time.

should I use Timer class for this or Quartz scheduler. please advice me a better solution. I am new to java so I'm not that familiar with these scheduler. if anyone can help me by giving a simple  example it'll be a great help for me how can I give the `timestamp` as parameter in `timer` .

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
 if (bur[i] > 0) {
    if (bur[i] > qtm) {
      execOrder.add(i + 1);
      bur[i] = bur[i] -qtm;
      flagClounter++;
    } else {
      execOrder.add(i + 1);
      bur[i] = 0;
      flagClounter++;
   }    
 }    
}
```

if the above is the code part ..how can I use it using timer and how to give the `Timestamp` there or in Quartz. please help me.

Comment: I will suggest to use Quartz Scheduler. Have a look at some of the tutorials for Quartz Scheduler at http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/quartz-scheduler-tutorial/

Comment: @BalwinderSingh thank you. and is it possible to trigger this code using MySQL trigger when that particular date and time comes. because the user when it request that time will be stored in the DB. so is it possible in that way???

Comment: You don't need to trigger this code using MYSQL trigger. Thats what Quartz Scheduler is for. I will suggest you to study the same and if it doesn't work then you can ask further queries.

Comment: Another choice is the [ScheduledExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) bundled with Java.

Answer (score 2):

Quartz scheduler is a very good option for achieving these kind of functionalities in java..Go with it.. http://www.tutorialsavvy.com/2012/12/quartz-scheduler-scheduling-job-in-java.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use Quartz triggers.. 
Basically quartz has two type of triggers
1. Simple Trigger 
2. Cron Trigger

Suppose if you want to run you Job on a particular Date and Time then use Cron Trigger. Cron trigger accepts Cron Expression which looks like below
expression=59 59 23 FRI * ?
Expression is says job should execute every Friday night at 11:59:59 PM
More expression can be obtained [here](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-1.x/tutorials/crontrigger).

On the other hand Simple trigger accepts milliseconds and executes once your application starts. i.e if Milliseconds specified is 10000, then job executes after 10000 milliseconds once application starts.

Comment: ,, thank you for the explanation.. so my program should run based on the user requests and the request for a particular date nd time which is stored in db in the form of timestamp. so based on your explanation I feel I should use cron triggers. but here the timestamp varies for each user. can I convert it in the form of millisecond and give it as a parameter to the trigger??